# Grid row does not update its colour when validation passes

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, telerik, telerik-grid

We have a Telerik Datagrid wherein we define a row validity based on properties of other rows (objects).

so as soon as one row's validation fails, all the related row turn their background red as well, but when we make data changes to pass the validation, the row under edit turns back to normal colour but others still remain RED i.e. they do not re assess themselves.

So my question is, when all rows turn red as soon as their validation fails why they don't turn back to normal as soon as validation passes ?

Validatable column is bound like this -

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Adjustments"
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors="InViewMode"
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Adjustment, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
<telerik:SumFunction Caption="Total: " />
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Thanks

M.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is evaluated using the indexer of `IDataErrorInfo` interface. This means, validation for a property only updates when the value is **read** through the interface.

In other words, causing each row to reload its values via a `PropertyChangedEvent` notification would cause the validation to clear.

Comment: then why do they go in error mode when I update just one ?

Comment: Are you touching the rows themselves in some way during the validation?